# Relationship between complement right-angled Coxeter groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a graph and $\bar{\Gamma}$ be its complement graph.
I am looking for a relationship between the respective right-angled Coxeter groups $G(\Gamma)$ and $G(\bar{\Gamma})$.

My intuition is that, as $\Gamma$ and $\bar{\Gamma}$ together give the complete graph $K_n$, we should be able to somehow divide the relations of $\bar{\Gamma}$ out of $G(\Gamma)$ to get $G(K_n) = \mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

When $E_n$ is the empty graph, $G(E_n) = \ast^n (\mathbb{Z}_2)$. By the definition of the RACGs, we have the maps $\phi_1: G(E_n) \twoheadrightarrow G(\Gamma)$ and $\phi_2: G(E_n) \twoheadrightarrow G(\bar{\Gamma})$.

When dividing out the relations given by $\bar{\Gamma}$ from $G(\Gamma)$, we get the map $\rho_1: G(\Gamma) \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ and analogously $\rho_2: G(\Gamma) \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

These maps should give a commutative square, $\rho_1 \circ \phi_1 = \rho_2 \circ \phi_2$. Is this square a pullback?

Also, can we relate $G(\Gamma)$ with $G(\bar{\Gamma})$ in some other way?

And what about when $\Gamma = \bar{\Gamma}$?

Comment: You have described the commutative square yourself, and that square gives a relation between $G(\Gamma)$ and $G(\bar\Gamma)$. What more are you asking?

Comment: For example whether the square is a pullback or whether we can somehow "quotient out" both of $G(\Gamma)$ and $G(\bar{\Gamma})$ of $G(E_n)$.

Comment: Or what it means when $\Gamma$ is self-dual.

Comment: Let me suggest that you hit the edit button and put these more specific questions into your post itself, in order to correct for the vagueness of the final question in the post.